# REACT How to access to a file from outside src folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm pretty new on React world. I'm working on a project and I'm trying to access to a file from outside the current *src* folder and I got such a strange error:

**Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../server.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.**

Any ideas of how I can fetch data from a file from outside *src* folder without getting this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have an idea.. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/

Comment: is src the root of your project? i.e. where your package.json is?